# Clarity about ESP32-C3FH4 pinout note

Tags: spi, esp32

I'm trying to incorporate an [ESP32-C3FH4](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c3_datasheet_en.pdf) into my design.

I've come across this note:

[image: Datasheet Note]

I'm not sure whether this means that I can use these pins for the relevant SPI controls (although I've no idea what `SPIQ`, `SPIWP`, or `SPIHD` are, but that's a different question), or not.

Comment: No. Usage of these pins interferes with the embedded flash.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this means this product contains both an ESP32 and a flash chip and this is how the flash chip is wired to the ESP32 - using these pins.

Notice on page 11, and 12 (footnote 7) the Z variant of the chip doesn't even connect these pins to the outside.

I would expect that on the non-Z variant, the pins are connected in parallel with the flash chip. Using them for non-flash purposes is not recommended because you need to make sure your usage doesn't interfere with the usage of the flash chip.